# Does there exist an international certification of mathematical skill?

Tags: teacher-preparation, certification, teacher-evaluations

I think that an international certification of math level would be really important also for non-math educators. Here in Italy primary school teachers actually teach math without being proficient at it. I was wondering, does there exist an international math certification program, analogous to the Common European Framework of Reference for Languages (CEFR)?

If I'd be a politician, I'd require teachers of every discipline to have at least a B2 in maths :)

Comment: Reputation on this website.

Comment: Well, it wás a joke. I don't know if it exists, but I don't think so, but I agree that it would be a good thing, just as it would be a good thing to internationalise other things such as the grades systems.

Comment: ah ok sorry! ^_^

Comment: Is there an agreed upon method of measuring mathematical skills?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How would you define a B2 in math?

Comment: The point is not what a viable definition of a B2 level in math should be, that is the work for an appropriate commission, but whether such a reference framework exists.

Comment: The last thing anyone needs are more certifications. We already waste enough time with those that exist.

Comment: I agree with Dan.  Certificates can be eluding, especially if handed out by the education system.  There is a very big difference between real-world mathematics, mathematics that people on mathoverflow do, and practice problems that your teacher gives you.

Comment: In the U.S., 54% of those who take the Praxis test on elementary-level content fail on their first try. 25% never manage to pass. Source: Forbes. So, not just the Italian problem.

Answer (score 1):

The International Baccalaureate program has a sequence of Math courses.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IB_Diploma_Programme

The mathematics section covers topics up to integral calculus.

Comment: Why the down vote? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I don't see how this answers the question.  Passing an IB exam means that you have, at best, passed the equivalent of an introductory calculus class.  It is not a certification of any kind.